# `suspendCoroutine` throws `This job has not completed yet` exception?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing, google-mlkit

I'm trying to test my encapsulated translator class which uses **Google ML Kit Translate** under the hood. I got an error that throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet`. I don't quite understand why this exception occurs. Has anyone ideas?

```kotlin
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineDispatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.resetMain
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runBlockingTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.setMain
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher
import org.junit.runner.Description
import timber.log.Timber
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

class GoogleMLKitTranslatorTest {

    private lateinit var translator: GoogleMLKitTranslator

    private val testValue = "Bana herhangi bir şey sor"

    @get:Rule
    var coroutinesTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        translator = GoogleMLKitTranslator()
        translator.initialize()

        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }

    @Test
    fun translate_turkish_test_to_english_should_return_true() =
        coroutinesTestRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
            val expectedValue = "Ask me anything"

            val translatedText = suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
                translator.translate(
                    value = testValue,
                    onSuccess = {
                        continuation.resume(it)
                    },
                    onFailure = {
                        continuation.resume(it.message ?: "Wow, something is wrong!")
                    }
                )
            }

            Timber.d("Translated text is $translatedText")
            assertThat(translatedText).matches(expectedValue)
        }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    class CoroutineTestRule(val testDispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()) : TestWatcher() {

        override fun starting(description: Description?) {
            super.starting(description)
            Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
        }

        override fun finished(description: Description?) {
            super.finished(description)
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
            testDispatcher.cleanupTestCoroutines()
        }
    }

}
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.getCompletionExceptionOrNull(JobSupport.kt:1128)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:53)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:80)
    at com.theteampotato.gifit.translate.GoogleMLKitTranslatorTest.translate_turkish_test_to_english_should_return_true(GoogleMLKitTranslatorTest.kt:46)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
    at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2258)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `runBlocking()` instead of `coroutinesTestRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest()` solved the problem somehow . Anyone who could reveal some useful insight is more than welcome.

Comment: I can't provide any further insight but there's an open issue on the coroutines repo with more info
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204